# Inconsistent Cassandra system.peers state

Tags: cassandra

We are running 6 nodes Cassandra (3.11.2) cluster on Kubernetess. Recently I noticed that the data in `system.peers` table is inconsistent. However, data in `system.local` seems to be ok. `nodetool describecluster` also doesn't report any issues.

Below you will find the anonymized result of system.peers and system.local queries. I executed them by forwarding port to a single node at a time (I hope this allows skipping load balancing policy and accessing node directly)

Is that state of a `system.peers` table is harmful? Or maybe it is expected?

`SELECT peer, schema_version FROM system.peers`

```
node 0
peer | schema_version
IP1 | schema2
IP2 | schema1
IP3 | schema1
IP4 | null
IP5 | schema1
IP6 | schema1
IP7 | schema1

node 1
peer | schema_version
IP8 | null
IP9 | schema1
IP3 | schema1
IP5 | schema1
IP6 | schema1
IP7 | schema1

node 2
peer | schema_version
IP11 | null
IP2 | schema1
IP9 | schema1
IP3 | schema1
IP4 | schema3
IP10 | null
IP5 | schema1
IP6 | schema1

node 3
peer | schema_version
IP12 | schema3
IP2 | schema1
IP9 | schema1
IP13 | null
IP3 | schema1
IP5 | schema1
IP7 | schema1

node 4
peer | schema_version
IP2 | schema1
IP9 | schema1
IP3 | schema1
IP6 | schema1
IP7 | schema1

node 5
peer | schema_version
IP8 | schema3
IP2 | schema1
IP9 | schema1
IP5 | schema1
IP6 | schema1
IP7 | schema1
```

`SELECT key, broadcast_address, schema_version FROM system.local`

```
node 0
key | broadcast_address | schema_version
local | IP9 | schema1

node 1
key | broadcast_address | schema_version
local | IP2 | schema1

node 2
key | broadcast_address | schema_version
local | IP7 | schema1

node 3
key | broadcast_address | schema_version
local | IP6 | schema1

node 4
key | broadcast_address | schema_version
local | IP5 | schema1

node 5
key | broadcast_address | schema_version
local | IP3 | schema1
```

`nodetool describecluster`

```
Cluster Information:
  Name: CLUSTER_NAME
  Snitch: org.apache.cassandra.locator.GossipingPropertyFileSnitch
  DynamicEndPointSnitch: enabled
  Partitioner: org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner
  Schema versions:
    e718e690-d474-376e-8020-ed0eba5b6797: [IP5, IP9, IP3, IP2, IP6, IP7]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is unexpected, but has been known to happen, for example: [CASSANDRA-7122](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-7122), [CASSANDRA-7531](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-7531).

This might cause issues for different client drivers (for example, see [JAVA-852](https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/JAVA-852) and [JAVA-2280](https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/JAVA-2280)), although most client libraries will ignore corrupt peers records like this and log a warning when it happens.

Since you mention Kubernetes, is it possible you are replacing nodes frequently?  I wonder if there is a latent bug in C* where it isn't properly removing old peers entries.  There have been issues reported in the past that have been closed with `COULD NOT REPRODUCE`.

If you can reproduce this rather easily, it would be super helpful to the community if you could [create a JIRA ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/CASSANDRA/issues) describing the issue and how to reproduce it.  Otherwise if you don't have the time, if you could describe your kubernetes set up (i.e. are you using a community operator or something else?) and explain some of the operations you may be doing that could contribute to this (i.e. replacing nodes) I could look into it when I get some time.